# Some stuff with content scripts - code runs not every time the page updates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to run some javascript code on every youtube page. But with this code it only runs if I re-upload the page. And if I just click link on youtube that goes to another youtube link, it does not work.
What needs to be changed?

> manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "Remove ads",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Remove ads and suggestions on youtube",

    "content_scripts": [{
       "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
       "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

> content.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

> script.js

```
alert("hello");
```

Comment: Youtube is a so-called AJAX-navigated site so you need to use events e.g. [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: That worked. Thank you!